# How do PHP and other languages pick random numbers?

Tags: php, random

Actually I was learning PHP, so this question just came into my mind. How does the computer pick a random number?

- What is the logic behind this random number generation?
- Is the computer using garbage values for random numbers?

Comment: I don't know why people are voting this down. "How are random numbers generated?" seems like a wholly reasonable question to me.

Comment: @lonesomeday - where do you see downvotes?

Comment: @j08691 Fair point: I actually meant close votes.

Comment: Guys don't put close votes. If you want to close just answer this and then close. I just want to know this.

Comment: PHP's `rand()` uses libc's random number generator.  While `mt_rand()` uses [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random numbers we normally have access to from code are called pseudorandom numbers. They are based on mathematical sequences of numbers that only repeat themselves after a very, very long time. The place to start in the sequence is based on the seed, which is normally taken as a function of time.

The numbers appear to be random, but in reality they're not, and that's why they're called "pseudorandom".

Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Comment: But, when this function rand()is called in php what happens actually behind the scene?

Comment: As I explained in my answer, the computer generates a sequence of numbers based on some pseudorandom algorithm and with the chosen seed (normally current time). When you call rand(), it gives you the next number in the sequence.

Comment: @FrozenKing, Check out the source code for [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and look at the `rand` method, then read up on Linear congruential generator (LCG).

Comment: one benefit of pseudo random numbers is that you can use the same seed over and over and get repeatable results.  Useful if you want to create random appearing data, but repeatably. One example is for filling a database with test data - you'd want it to be the same every time, but you might want variety to make it look real.

Comment: @TimG a useful application for what you are suggesting is in games. If you want to make spawning etc look random, but let different players have a similar and fair experience, then you can use the same seed for each session.

Comment: @Gigi Hey does this pseudorandom has to do any thing with garbage values. I heard that random numbers are usually taken from garbage values?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "garbage values". To obtain pure randomness you'd need something like a device to capture randomly decaying particles in a radioactive substance. In general this means random noise... not an easy thing to achieve when considering that computers are deterministic.

Comment: So, garbage values and this pseudorandom functions are two different things !! Does this pseudorandom function also present in c,c++,java etc languages. And, are this pseudorandom function and the garbage values the same?

Comment: As far as I know, all languages use pseudorandom numbers. What do you mean exactly by "garbage values"?

Comment: I don't know much about the garbage values, but I heard it in c and c++ concepts. My teachers used to tell that random values are picked in c and c++ from garbage collector.

Comment: Oh no, that's something entirely different. First of all C/C++ does not have garbage collection. Garbage values and garbage collection are two different things. Garbage collection refers to languages like C# which automatically deallocate objects when they are no longer used. In C/C++, if you access the wrong part of memory, then you get unexpected data, and that's why it's called garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the programming / scripting language there are so called pseudo-random values. Because computers don't really have the option to just pick a number that comes to their minds (heh!), there's an algorithm / calculation that creates the number. The principle is very simple. The random value you get is only random because the way it is calculated is not known to you. If you had a randomizer function running for a while without changing it's seed (a value you can enter to change the calculation in the background) the values it gives would reoccur.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation), its fairly good explained there.

Most computer random number are pseudo random. If you want really random numbers, you have to use white noise as a source, and digitize that.